# Fortran Mismatch in components of derived type

Tags: cmake, fortran, gfortran

I am currently developing a software in Fortran. It has been already a couple of times I've encountered the error below. Previously I just managed to undo those changes and rewrite the code again as I was not able to understand the issue.

Obviously, the issue came back again. So I am wondering why it happens. What am I doing in the code thats triggering it.

The compiler used is gfortran-9. I also tried to compile in gfortran-10 (ubuntu 20.04) with the hope it was a compiler bug already solved :/. The error shown is the same but with different elements.

This part of the software consists in a library (modules starting with SIO_...) which is using another one (modules starting with SHR_...).

Project structure:

- soulio (library folder)

  - src
  - tests/unit
  - soulshared (external library)

The file triggering the error at compilation times is soulio/tests/unit/ncSpatialFile.F90. It has the following imports:

```
module ncSpatialFile_test

  use netcdf

  use SHR_file_mod, only: removeIfExists
  use SHR_testSuite_mod, only: testSuite
  use SHR_datetime_mod, only: datetime, timedelta, clock
  
  use SIO_ncSpatialFile_mod, only: ncSpatialFile_abs <- gfortran-9 complains about this line
  ...
```

Imports from soulio/src/ncSpatialFile_abs.F90

```
module SIO_ncSpatialFile_abs

!  use netcdf
  use SHR_datetime_mod, only: clock, datetime, timedelta
  use SHR_strings_mod, only: string
  use SHR_precision_mod, only: sp
  use SHR_array_mod, only: initArrayRange
  use SHR_error_mod, only: raiseError

  use SIO_ncfile_mod, only: ncfile
  use SIO_ncDimensions_mod, only: ncDimensions
  use SIO_ncVariables_mod, only: ncVariables
  use SIO_grid_mod, only: grid
  use SIO_parallel_mod, only: mpiContext_type
  use SIO_ncSlimSpatialDims_mod, only: ncSlimSpatialDims
  use SIO_ncFullSpatialDims_mod, only: ncFullSpatialDims
  use SIO_ncSpatialDims_abs, only: ncSpatialDims

  use SIO_ncParams_mod, only: NC_TIME_DIM_NAME, NC_SPATIAL_DIM_NAME!, SIO_NC_GLOBAL_ATTR
  use SIO_ncOtherDim_mod, only: ncOtherDim
  use SIO_ncTimeDim_mod, only: ncTimeDim
  use SIO_ncVar_mod, only: ncVar
  use SIO_ncDim_mod, only: ncDim, ncDimHolder
  use SIO_ncTime_mod, only: ncTime
  use SIO_ncDimensionsRequest_mod, only: ncDimensionsRequest
  use SIO_ncVariableBounds_mod, only: ncVariableBounds
  use SIO_ncAttributes_mod, only: ncAttributes

  ... (too many imports?)

  type, abstract :: ncSpatialFile_abs
    ! netcdf file interface
    class(ncfile), allocatable :: ncfile

    ! time series
    class(clock), allocatable :: ncClock
```

soulio/soulshared/src/datetime_mod.F90

```
module SHR_datetime_mod

  use iso_fortran_env, only: real32, real64
  use iso_c_binding, only: c_char, c_int, c_null_char
  use SHR_error_mod, only: raiseError

  implicit none

  private

  public :: datetime, timedelta, clock, calendar
  ...
```

Error in gfortran-10:

```
soulio/tests/unit/ncSpatialFile_test.F90:20:7:

   20 |   use SIO_ncSpatialFile_mod, only: ncSpatialFile_abs
      |       1
Fatal Error: Mismatch in components of derived type ‘__vtype_shr_datetime_mod_Calendar’ from ‘shr_datetime_mod’ at (1): expecting ‘calendar_assign’, but got ‘getdaysinmonth’
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [tests/unit/CMakeFiles/soulio_test.dir/build.make:232: tests/unit/CMakeFiles/soulio_test.dir/ncSpatialFile_test.F90.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:260: tests/unit/CMakeFiles/soulio_test.dir/all] Error 2
```

Error in gfortran-9:

```
soulio/tests/unit/ncSpatialFile_test.F90:20:6:

   20 |   use SIO_ncSpatialFile_mod, only: ncSpatialFile_abs
      |      1
Fatal Error: Mismatch in components of derived type ‘__vtype_shr_datetime_mod_Clock’ from ‘shr_datetime_mod’ at (1): expecting ‘currenttickintervals’, but got ‘clock_assign’
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [tests/unit/CMakeFiles/soulio_test.dir/build.make:232: tests/unit/CMakeFiles/soulio_test.dir/ncSpatialFile_test.F90.o] Error 1
```

The error came up after modifing ncSpatialFile_test but not datetime.

I find the error confusing. Any ideas about what the compiler is trying to say? Any other advice in how to dig further?

Edit:

Datetime_mod file is taken from https://github.com/wavebitscientific/datetime-fortran. There are a few modifications but its the same structure.

clock declaration:

```
type :: clock
    type(datetime) :: startTime
    type(datetime) :: stopTime
    type(datetime) :: currentTime
    type(datetime) :: prevTime !> currentTime - 1 timestep
    type(datetime) :: nextTime !> currentTime + 1 timestep
    type(timedelta) :: tickInterval
    logical :: alarm = .false.
    logical :: started = .false.
    logical :: stopped = .false.
    logical :: nullified = .false. !< it is considered not defined
  contains
    procedure :: getStartTime
    procedure :: getStopTime
    procedure :: reset
    procedure :: tick
    procedure :: toString => toString_clock
    procedure :: isStopped
    procedure :: isNull
    ! true  when the condition is satisfied for the current time step
    procedure :: isBeginYear, isEndYear
    procedure :: isBeginMonth, isEndMonth
    procedure :: isBeginDay, isEndDay
    procedure :: isBeginClock, isEndClock
    procedure :: getTickIntervals
    procedure :: totalTickIntervals
    procedure :: currentTickIntervals
    !
    procedure, private :: clock_assign
    procedure, private, pass(from) :: clock_assign_tickInterval

    generic :: assignment(=) => clock_assign,   clock_assign_tickInterval

    procedure :: findEquivalentCurrentTime
    procedure :: getCalendarType => getCalendarType_clock

    procedure, private :: equiv_clock
    generic :: operator(==) => equiv_clock

    procedure :: isInAbsoluteBounds
  end type clock
```

Comment: It would be helpful if we could see the declaration of the `Clock` type in `datetime_mod.F90`.

Comment: Have you tried running `make clean; make` or equivalent? It could be a caching issue.

Comment: Are you sure there aren't two classes named `Clock` in your project?

Comment: The project is managed by cmake. I normally remove the build folder and then recompile the whole project. There has to be something missing(?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @veryreverie in the comments section, it was a problem of cache.

The cmake project places its mod files into tree project/lib. Those files are not removed when I clean the build folder. Because of this, some inconsistencies were happening.